# Running JSF gives me download file box

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jboss

I am running JSF Project on jboss Server 5.0, When it is deployed the browser gives me download file message instead of showing the xhtml Content

here my web.xml :

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<h1> Test</h1>
<h:form>
<h:inputText value="test"  />
</h:form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Insufficient Information

Comment: Stab in the dark: have you configured the Faces Servlet? If yes, please show us the relevant parts of your `web.xml` file.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't be showing the XHTML content, but the generated HTML output based on the parsed XHTML content ... Browsers only understand HTML, not XHTML. Perhaps this is where you had a conceptual misunderstanding? In case of JSF, the `FacesServlet` is the one responsible for this job. So, listen to what @mabi suggests. In the meanwhile, those wiki pages should be enlightening: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: @BalusC thank you for your answer ,I know it should show me the HTML output , now nothing appears , just a downlod file box

Comment: The symptom of the download box being shown confirms that it didn't return HTML content or at least any content which is natively supported by the browser. The fact that it didn't return HTML content suggests that the `FacesServlet` is not being invoked. The fact that it is mapped on an URL pattern of `/faces/*` suggests that the request URL (as you see in browser's address bar) doesn't match that URL pattern. Does it make sense now...? Wouldn't you rather change the URL pattern of `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml` so that it's invoked on URLs matching `*.xhtml`?